# Question about becoming a full stack developer

Tags: job-search, continuing-education

I’m currently set to graduate with my bachelors in software development in August. I feel like I am completely ill prepared for a job. So I have been looking into how to hone my skills and came across CareerKarma and they get you into boot camps and supposedly Into a job by the end of the year.

My question is: As someone who is receiving his bachelors but isn’t confident in his skills as a developer/coder yet, would It be beneficial to do a boot camp at the same time or to self teach myself? My biggest concern is paying back student loans and also a boot camp loan or Income sharing agreement.

Comment: It depends on the person. Anyone can teach themselves how to code, but some people learn better working with other people and being taught/asking questions. Other people like to google problems and search forums for answers. Choose which one is most suitable for you as a person.

Comment: The main point of the bootcamp is the credential. Since you are getting a degree proper you do not need that credential

Comment: This is probably better on a stack about coding / teaching / studying...

Comment: @SolarMike, If this question gets transferred to the programming StackExchange, it will get closed for sure. Please make sure you know the rules of the StackExchange in question before transferring questions to it.

Comment: Do you know how to write a while loop in pseudo-code? Can you communicate what you know/understand and what you don't know/understand? Can you take notes during meetings and use them to recall in detail a week later what that meeting was about? Can you read and understand documentation, e.g. javadocs? Do you usually find the results you need if you use google? If that's all the case, the only thing you may lack for a junior position is a grain of self-esteem.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I did not pick programming but there are other stacks which you have not considered in your analysis...

Answer (score 5):

To be cruel, I could say that if you don't have the skills by now, then it is unlikely that you can cram them before August.

In reality, I would ask why you feel that way (by not telling us, you make it difficult for us to help you).

But my answer is: [Don't panic!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Don't_Panic) You are about to "level up" your life. Bigly. Can you remember the jump from school to university? The jump from uni to "real life" is an order of magnitude greater.

It is natural to feel a little lack of self confidence at this point. Don't lose sight of that.

The reality is (or was, when I graduated with  B.SC Comp Sci a "few" decades ago, that 1) university does not prepare you for industry and 2) industry knows that.

Generally, having a degree is just a filter that says to us "reasonably intelligent, probably trainable, worth interviewing, should train well".

We expect to have to train you.

We do not expect university to teach you about requirements gathering & analysis, software architecture, detailed design, reviewing, unit testing, integration testing, continuous integration or test driven design.

At best, we hope for you to be able to code and debug (somewhat).

When I am interviewing new grads, I am aware of that. "Seems bright and eager to learn" is about the best that I can hope for. It helps if you can explain a project that you did at uni; how you designed it and what problems you faced. Beyond that, we will train you. In about 18 months, you might become productive.

---

Tl'dr; don't worry, a degree and a positive attitude should land you a job, which will train you, and after that your future is yours to shape.

Comment: Thanks for that reassurance.  That’s kind of the understanding I’ve had, is that I will be trained and a job won’t expect me to know everything fresh out of school.  As for as my skills go? I’m confident in what I know, just not quite enough for a job.  But I also have 7 months left so I’m sure I’ll learn a lot coming up.  I’m gonna stick with this degree and code on the side and just start applying.  Thank you

Comment: Don't worry too much. We all went through it. Even the guys who will interview you. Good luck :-)

Comment: "Generally, having a degree is just a filter.... " I want to do +100 just for that one bit because it is **so** true.

Comment: If only there were another filter pointing to "reasonably intelligent" that didn't cost so much !

Answer (score 1):

I talk to a lot of developers in your position. I'm a senior back-end and CTO.

Boot camps are not worth the money, especially considering you are about to get a degree. You will never feel job ready...

I see many developers get stuck in a cycle of trying to learn everything, and as things update so fast in this industry, they never finish learning and never feel ready to apply for a job. After getting a job they realise they wasted most of their time learning things that never get used.

Don't waste money on a boot camp. Apply to every junior position you can, eventually you will get something. You can think of a junior position as boot camp, except you get paid to do it and learn real industry standards.

Companies with junior positions don't expect you to have all the skills, they want someone they can train from the ground up.

Most of what you have been taught at uni isn't how we do things in the professional industry. The same with boot camps. The only way to learn the skills you need is by getting that first job.

Comment: This answer is everything, I really appreciate it.  Everyone seems to be leaning towards “finish the degree, and get your job” instead of attending an expensive boot camp.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you went to a decent school, chances are high that they taught you the science of computer science (and not the practical side of programming).

If that's the case, don't worry too much. Most employers know this. If you're fresh out of school (and didn't do a coop), you'll be mostly tested on data structures and algorithms anyway and usually on only one language.

If you want to test yourself, check out:

https://pramp.com

https://interviewing.io

https://leetcode.com

https://www.careercup.com/ (check out the book Cracking the Coding Interview)

With that said, if your degree was really on "software development" and not computer science, then it probably means you've already done the coding bootcamp route, you just did it through your school.

Second of all, the address listed on the CareerKarma web site is a residential building, not an actual business.

And looking at their web site, it doesn't look like they offer their own coding bootcamps, they just cross-promote the coding bootcamps of others. Which brings me to my next point. Be very careful if you go the bootcamp route. Many offer significant commissions to their alumni (or to other organizations like this one).

And if an alumnus is going to receive $5,000 for selling you on a $28,000 bootcamp, that person is not going to be honest with you. They have every reason not to be. The same goes for the testimonials on their web site.

With that said, I'd suggest you watch this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSgsX80ymF8). It's not mine, but it outlines some of the reasons you should not be going to a coding bootcamp right now, especially now that there are so many of them.

Comment: Stephan thanks for that!  I knew about the residential building and everything, CareerKarma is a start up, that you guessed it, does cross promote these boot camps.  I think I’m just getting to eager because I’m so close and kind of freaking myself out I guess.  But you’re right, my degree is teaching me a lot of concepts that are sticking and allowing me to actually grasp a technical conversation with someone and even explain some things.  I appreciate that extra research as well.  I’m gonna just keep coding on the side while I finish this degree.  Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

> I feel like I am completely ill prepared for a job.

**Verify that you are actually ill prepared**

I am in my first job out of university and got hired without knowing either framework in our stack and had never used the languages for a serious project. The skills I hadn't used in years(Java) or on a very minimal basis (JavaScript) were the ones that found me a job. It was a very surprising outcome.

Once I got here, I took two weeks to learn the frameworks and after that, I was fixing bugs. In 6 weeks, I was being given tasks just like the other developers.

Try applying to jobs and seeing what happens.

Comment: Perfect, me and my wife were kind of at a cross roads because of this.  I mean I am confident in my skills, just don’t feel job ready, and I have been using Java and JavaScript daily because that’s what I’ve been reading lately.  I really appreciate that advice.  I probably am just going to finish out school and continue self learning on the side with more in depth coding.  There’s a lot of free stuff that I already have.  Thank you

Comment: "`Verify that you are actually ill prepared`"  - no need to verify - he ***is*** ill-prepared. ***Everyone*** is/was -for their first (programming) job. He just has to know & accept this and not blow the interview with nerves (although we make allowances for that). You know yourself how it is (was recently). If he is getting reasonable grades, I am sure that he will land a job

Answer (score -1):

> As someone who is receiving his bachelors but isn’t confident in his skills as a developer/coder yet

I believe you are not alone in this one. Most graduates are not well-equipped for what the industry has to offer. What is being taught in school is nothing compared to what is being used in the industry. It's alright to not be confident at this time. It can be overwhelming too. But remember this is just the beginning of your career. You still have much to learn.

> would It be beneficial to do a boot camp at the same time or to self teach myself?

Both. In order to survive in our industry, we must learn to adapt. Technologies come and go. New technology stack appears and can replace what is popular now. Bootcamps are great but don't depend on it solely for your source of learning. Look for other resources online. There are a lot of MOOCs right now and most of them are free(and great!). ***"Self-teaching"***  is the key.

> My biggest concern is paying back student loans and also a boot camp loan or Income sharing agreement.

If you are going to have a problem with bootcamp loan, then I suggest you take free MOOCs instead as I've stated above. Coursera, udemy, udacity, scrimba etc. (I use these MOOCs too)

I am a recent graduate and now working as a software developer. It is a big world out there. But always remember, ***the world is your oyster*** :)

Comment: These are all great comments man, thanks for referring to every part of the question.  I’m going to finish this degree this year, start self teaching myself, I do have a full stack boot camp I paid 20 for on udemy.  Next step is applying this summer . I really appreciate it